# Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map Gradlew Error

Tags: java, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

I am trying to skid a minecraft client but I keep getting errors like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
```

The source code: https://github.com/IUDevman/gamesense-client

With --stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.getWindowsEnv(WrapperProcess.java:127)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setEnvInternal(WrapperProcess.java:100)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setEnvironmentVariable(WrapperProcess.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.setNativeEnvironmentVariable(NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.setEnvironmentVariable(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.maybeSetEnvironment(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3f0ee7cb
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:181)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:175)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.getWindowsEnv(WrapperProcess.java:124)
        ... 16 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Gradlew version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-12-05 00:50:54 UTC
Revision:     e76905e3a1034e6f724566aeb985621347ff43bc

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9-29)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

JDK Version: 20.0

Yes, I did input the JDK in the JAVA_HOME and Path.

Comment: Gradle 4? That's ancient. No idea if that's the problem, but I doubt it's compatible with Java 20.

Comment: I'm not sure Gradle 4 can support Java 20 honestly, consider gradle upgrade first

Comment: 1.12.2 Forge, I believe, only allows Grade 4 but when I try to change my JAVA_HOME to an older version such as JDK11 It still show the same error.

Comment: You need to explicitly open the package to all unnamed modules, by providing `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`. I have no idea how to do this in Gradle though.